# AWS JS SDK throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'crypto' of undefined

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

My following code:

```
  var AWS = require('./aws-sdk-2.2.10.js') // THIS LINE ERRORS
```

Produces the follwing error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'crypto' of undefined
```

This is the part of aws-sdk-2.2.10.js that is throwing the error

```
...
65: [function(require, module, exports) {
  (function() {
    var _global = this; // I think 'this' is undefined here
    var mathRNG, whatwgRNG;
    mathRNG = function(size) {
        var bytes = new Array(size);
        var r;
        for (var i = 0, r; i < size; i++) {
            if ((i & 0x03) == 0)
                r = Math.random() * 0x100000000;
            bytes[i] = r >>> ((i & 0x03) << 3) & 0xff;
        }
        return bytes;
    }
    ;
    if (_global.crypto && crypto.getRandomValues) { // THIS LINE ERRORS
        whatwgRNG = function(size) {
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(size);
            crypto.getRandomValues(bytes);
            return bytes;
        }
        ;
    }
    module.exports = whatwgRNG || mathRNG;
  }
  )();
}
...
```

My code is built via webpack and my code lives in the entry file, app.js.

I'm not sure why this wouldn't work?

Edit: If it matters, my end goal is to use Parse's CloudCode to put and get files from s3

Comment: Hi. I'm having the same issue, did you manage to solve this somehow?

Comment: @JorgeChayan I didn't :(

Comment: I found the issue, apparently the AWS SDK uses CyptoJS and I was missing the "core.js" file under the "components" subdirectory from this library. I just added it and voilà. c: